# How can I hide a table with css and jquery, which has values a database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I have problem. I have one database in which I want to take her values and show them on a html table. I have already created the database and her tables and with jQuery I hide and show it with one button from a dropdown list. The problem is that i want to show this table when I click the button and all the other time I want it to be hidden. For this reason I have the display:none; on css. But when I do this, I can see only the first row of the database. And I delete display:none; I can see all the rows but this is shown for ever on my page. Where am I wrong?

**jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#p4').click(function(){ //p4 id για το κουμπί της dropdown λίστας
$('#table4').show();
$('#table5').show();
  });
 });
</script>
```

**php**

```
<table name="table4" id="table4" width="941" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="8%"><b>No.</b></td>
<td width="8%"><b>Όνομα</b></td>
<td width="11%"><b>Επώνυμο</b></td>
<td width="11%"><b>Πατρώνυμο</b></td>
<td width="9%"><b>Διεύθυνση Κατοικίας</b></td>
<td width="6%"><b>Πόλη</b></td>
<td width="7%"><b>ΤΚ</b></td>
<td width="7%"><b>ΑΜΚΑ</b></td>
<td width="7%"><b>Τηλέφωνο</b></td>
<td width="7%"><b>E-mail</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
// Run the actual connection here  
$link=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysqli_select_db($link,"$dbname") or die ("no database");        
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM lista_asthenwn");
$astheneis = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<table name="table5" id="table5" class="table5" width="941" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="13%"><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
<td width="13%"><?php echo $row['Onoma']?></td>
<td width="9%"><?php echo $row['Epwnumo']?></td>
<td width="6%"><?php echo $row['Patrwnumo']?></td>
<td width="21%"><?php echo $row['Dieuthunsh']?></td>
<td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Poli']?></td>
<td width="9%"><?php echo $row['TK']?></td>
<td width="10%"><?php echo $row['AMKA']?></td>
<td width="8%"><?php echo $row['Til']?></td>
<td width="3%"><?php echo $row['Email']?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
// close while loop
}
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**css**

```
#table4 {
margin-top: 150px;
display:none;
}
#table5 {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping over rows instead of tables -- don't close the `table` tag after your head, only close it after the whole table is out.

You are currently repeating `id` (table5) which should be unique! jQuery (correctly) expects that each `id` will only occur once in the page, and as such only returns the first element when an `id` selector is used ( https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ ).

```
<table name="table4" id="table4" width="941" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="8%"><b>No.</b></td>
    <td width="8%"><b>Όνομα</b></td>
    <td width="11%"><b>Επώνυμο</b></td>
    <td width="11%"><b>Πατρώνυμο</b></td>
    <td width="9%"><b>Διεύθυνση Κατοικίας</b></td>
    <td width="6%"><b>Πόλη</b></td>
    <td width="7%"><b>ΤΚ</b></td>
    <td width="7%"><b>ΑΜΚΑ</b></td>
    <td width="7%"><b>Τηλέφωνο</b></td>
    <td width="7%"><b>E-mail</b></td>
  </tr>

  <?php
    // Run the actual connection here  
    $link=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"$dbname") or die ("no database");        
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM lista_asthenwn");
    $astheneis = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td width="13%"><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
    <td width="13%"><?php echo $row['Onoma']?></td>
    <td width="9%"><?php echo $row['Epwnumo']?></td>
    <td width="6%"><?php echo $row['Patrwnumo']?></td>
    <td width="21%"><?php echo $row['Dieuthunsh']?></td>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Poli']?></td>
    <td width="9%"><?php echo $row['TK']?></td>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['AMKA']?></td>
    <td width="8%"><?php echo $row['Til']?></td>
    <td width="3%"><?php echo $row['Email']?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    // close while loop
    endwhile;

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
  ?>
</table>
```

Since you want to loop this way, I've changed the `while` loop to use angled the php-as-a-template style ( `:` and `endwhile` ).

Comment: It works for me. Thank you so so so much my friend! :)